# How to exit from if statement That has been In table for display some of th tag In Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a asp mvc project and I want diplay a list in partial view.
I display it by a table but I don't want show all th tag.Consider the following code:

```
@if(bool.parse(option1)&&bool.parse(option2))
{

<th>Country</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>City</th>
}

@if(bool.parse(option1))
{
  <th>Country</th>
  <th>City</th>
}
  @if(bool.parse(option2))
{
   <th>State</th>
}

<th>other columns</th>
```

I want if option1 and option2 is true no running 2th and 3th condition and display other columns.How do you do it

Answer (score 1):

Use `else if` like this:

```
@if(bool.parse(option1)&&bool.parse(option2))
{
<th>Country</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>City</th>
}
else if(bool.parse(option1))
{
  <th>Country</th>
  <th>City</th>
}
else if(bool.parse(option2))
{
   <th>State</th>
}

<th>other columns</th>
```

**EDIT** if you want to do it without `else` (I have no idea why), try this:

```
@if(bool.parse(option1))
{
  <th>Country</th>
}
@if(bool.parse(option2))
{
   <th>State</th>
}
@if(bool.parse(option1))
{
  <th>City</th>
}

<th>other columns</th>
```

I prefer this style anyway, not because I don't want to use `else`, but because it looks cleaner with no redundancy.

Comment: I want try to do it without else but ur answer is correct.thank u so much.